# How to find the descending part of a vector and remove it?

Tags: matlab, vector, indices

I have a vector like `A = [20 30 40 50 60 55 54 60 70]`. It is always ascending until the invalid value (here for ex. `55`), I need to find the indices of this element and remove all elements after that. my desired vectror is [20 30 40 50 60]
any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

short answer:

```
A(find(diff(A)<0,1)+1:end) = []
```

longer answer with explanation:

[`diff`](http://en.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) calculates the difference between adjacent elements:

```
>> diff(A)

ans =

10    10    10    10    -5    -1     6    10
```

We then search the first index of those differences that is less than zero and remove this and all succeeding elements.

```
>>> idx = find(diff(A)<0,1)+1

idx =

 6

>>> A(idx:end)

ans =

55    54    60    70

>> A(idx:end) = []

A =

20    30    40    50    60
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance but it actually gives me the unwanted elements.
I used your tip :
n=find(diff(A)<0,1)
A=A(1:n)
now it works perfect :)

Comment: @Maryam It works for me with your demo vector, what unwanted elements do you get? did you forget the `= []` part?

Comment: @m.s. sorry at first I didn't use [ ] , that's why I got the wrong part.

Comment: @m.s. - Come by our MATLAB chat room when you have the time and say hi :) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave